# Store RSA public key into Android Keystore

Tags: android, kotlin, rsa, android-keystore

I'm trying to insert a public key into Android Keystore (also generated by Android Keystore) as an X509 certificate as:

```
 // Convert String into a public key
 val keyText = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxfA62QI++RO45nV241wEUT19DtaiF/49PKfCiUeoVu6tSb4us0Whl1i1u76cznWeTgBuqOXPt67feoegaIs6kMT1FMFNK9bHU02ufQ9DhmC/cLknXZtYHfxaerAUVdL1b8maKuXmkxiIBjAOU57PdSLapG29a41+Z9wWmHW5NMq11PZFlW9qFJ+Splq1EV9NDFsMbN9WAqGhRO1tnyj3DaqsYnS/HKyuym9J2KVWJSVUMrXcNDm9uUnchdCJ4QkPQQbDJ/QQVFCM1q7XSgNAgR/7UAlN8tdb0QobIhG0S6QGGhgodYDS397fDPAEtX2CK8VVpQOmbrjrZWKGLQ2bqQIDAQAB"
 val decodedKeyBytes = Base64.decode(keyText, Base64.DEFAULT)
 val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKeyBytes)
 val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
 val newPubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)

 val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
 val x509Certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(
     newPubKey.encoded.inputStream()
   ) as X509Certificate

 // Insert into AndroidKeyStore
 val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply {load(null)}
 ks.setCertificateEntry("KEY_UID", x509Certificate)
```

I get the following exception while trying to generate the X509 certificate from the public key:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: 
  com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c00006d:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECODE_ERROR 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:303)
```

I'm sure `newPubKey` is correct, since it matches the object originally produced by the Android Keystore.
Am I missing some configuration for the X509 certificate? Is it even possible to store a public key as a certificate? Is there any other way of doing it?

Thank you

Comment: A `CertificateEntry` is for certificates. An RSA public key is not a certificate. Use `KeyEntry`, or better still wrap your key in a certificate.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for your hints. If I try `setKeyEntry` with the public key as `setKeyEntry("KEY_UID", newPubKey, null, null)`, I get a `java.security.KeyStoreException: Only PrivateKey and SecretKey are supported` exception. I like what you suggest about wrapping the key in a certificate. I believe it's what I'm trying in the code above, to wrap the key in an X509 Certificate. However, I get an exception while creating the certificate. Sorry, I forgot to add part of the code. Now it's complete. :s

Comment: Again, an RSA public key is not a certificate. `generateCertificate()` expects a certificate input stream, not a key input stream. These `generate` methods are poorly named. They don't generate anything, they *reconstruct* things that already exist. They are really de-serializers. You're not *creating* a new certificate here.

Comment: @user207421I see, I will try to research how to do it. Thanks for the pointer to the problem :)

Comment: @Gabriel You would need the private key to e.g. generate a self signed cert or maybe another key pair and CA certificate to sign the certificate if you cannot use the private key. You may need Bouncy Castle PKIX library to generate the certificates. However, I'm really wondering first what you are trying to achieve. Could you fill us in on the "why"?

Comment: Me too. If this is your own public key, you already have its private key, and you either already have or can create a wrapping self-signed certificate for it with the` keytool` or `openssl.exe`. If it's someone else's public key, they should have supplied it to you in the form of a certificate. I don't understand why you need to write all this in code.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes @user207421 Thanks for your comments. I'm sorry I didn't say why, but every time I tried to write anything else than the problem itself in stackoverflow, my question was edited by someone to delete any kind of context. Indeed, it is someone else's RSA public key and I would like to store it in the best way possible, to be able to generate encrypted messages for this person. It's all part of an educational application I'm writing so I can change the way public keys are exchanged. I just thought that sharing text encoded `PublicKey` objects was the shortest way...(continue below)

Comment: Currently, I was trying to implement it by sharing base64 encoded text of `val pubKey = ks.getCertificate("keyAlias")?.publicKey` as `Base64.encodeToString(pubKey?.encoded, Base64.DEFAULT)`. Would it be better trying to share an encoded version of `ks.getCertificate("keyAlias")`? I assumed it was going to be a longer text and I wanted it to be as short as possible because I would like to share it via QR code. Maybe you can suggest me a better/ more standard way of doing it. I really appreciate it

Comment: `RSAPublicKey#getEncoded` will give you a SubjectPublicKeyInfo object (the public key as present in an X.509 certificate, including type indication). You can distribute this in PEM format (which e.g. Bouncy Castle provides code for). [PEM encoding of the SPKI has been specified in RFC 7468](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468#section-13). That's probably the most compatible option - other than an X.509 certificate of course. For a QR code you could use the SPKI or the contains PKCS#1 format as binary encoding is shorter.

Comment: (or, if you control the standard, just set the e value of the RSA public key to 0x10001 and simply encode just the modulus for the QR code, then use `RSAPublicKeySpec` to recreate the public key using a `KeyFactory`, that's even shorter)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks! So, if I understood, what I posted as `keyText` is the SPKI. I can distribute it in PEM format by adding the begin/end labels and it will be consistent with standards. However, I still have the same problem: Once I get a new SPKI, how to insert it into Keystore for later retrieval? Is it possible to wrap it in an X.509 certificate without the corresponding private key so that I can store it? Of course, I could just store the key in a file but wanted to know if Keystore could be used somehow, since I understand it is "safer" (e.g., avoid key replacement/modification)

Comment: I don't think that is a great solution. But free of charge I'll provide you with another idea: put a self signed signing cert in the keystore and then sign the public key. If you do that then an adversary cannot change the public key file, although they can of course destroy it given enough access (you could make it read only maybe to avoid that attack). You could also use the self signed cert to create a certificate around your public key and then store it. No access to the private key required for this.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for the ideas. As you said, I see that these options to force the storage of public keys alone in Android keystore seem "wrong". I guess I should either store the received public key in a plain database together with my contact info (given that I trust the source and the physical process through which I got the key) or just share the public key together with the signature, e.g., via PEM encoding of X.509 cert. (I hope it is viable to share all this data via reasonably small QR code). Thanks again and if you have any other suggestion, it is welcome.

Comment: Well according to the code in your comment you actually did start with the other party's certificate. So I would just keep doing that. It's already signed and all that so everything mentioned here is covered.

Comment: @user207421 Well, I start with the other party's public key, not with its certificate. So I guess I will just change the process and share the X.509 cert directly. The only thing is that it's a little longer text and the QR is bigger and more "difficult" to read (squares are smaller for the same size).